# Different predictions on multiple run of the same algorithm scikit neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

Since a MLP can implement any function. I have the following code, using which I am trying to implement the AND function. But what I find that on running the program multiple times, I end up getting different predicted values. Why is this happening ? Also how does one determine which type of activation function has to be provided at different layers ?

```
from sknn.mlp import Regressor,Layer,Classifier
import numpy as np   
X_train = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y_train = np.array([0,0,0,1])
nn = Classifier(layers=[Layer("Softmax", units=2),Layer("Linear", units=2)],learning_rate=0.001,n_iter=25)
nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_example = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y_example = nn.predict(X_example)
print (y_example)
```

Comment: For classification is often a scalarproduct used, For your problem you need exactly 1 neuron. The Layers determine wich regions one can classify. 1 Layer half plane, 2 layer convex region, 3 layers every region

Comment: What about the fact that I am getting different prediction ?

Comment: It is likely because the starting weights are randomly generated.  You should probably explore how to set the random seed for the consistency you want.

Comment: What shud I do to get a 100% accuracy on testing my model on the training data for the simple AND function ?

Answer (score 0):

-The different values obtained for every run is because your weights are randomly initialized.
-Activation functions have different properties. You can either use your experience to decide which is best for your situation, or you can read how they work (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115258/comprehensive-list-of-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-with-pros-cons)